# Required Mark next to Apex:inputText and showing required error message

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component, required

There is requirement to put the required mark next to Apex:inputText. And also, required error message I want to show near to apex:InputText (bottom).
Whie searching I found there are ways:

> a.  Using outputPanel tag

```
<apex:column headerValue="test1">
        <apex:outputPanel styleClass="requiredInput">
        <apex:outputPanel id="thePanel" styleClass="requiredBlock" /> 
        <apex:inputText value="{!obj.numberOfP}" required="true"/>

</apex:column>
```

> b.  Using div tag

```
<apex:column headerValue="test1">
   <div class = "requiredInput">
      <div class = "requiredBlock"></div> 
      <apex:inputText value="{!obj.numberOfP}" required="true"/>
   </div>
</apex:column>
```

Since Salesforce strongly recommends that we should use Visualforce components that mimic the look-and-feel of Salesforce styles instead of directly referencing—and depending upon—Salesforce stylesheets, can anyone suggests the best recommended approach by salesforce.

Answer (score 2):

Well, there are two approaches here (Classic)

**Define styles in your VF page so you aren't relying on the SFDC styles.**

This is what the inestimable Keir Bowden aka Bob Buzzard, does in *[Visualforce Cookbook Second Edition Recipe: Styling fields as Required](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/visualforce-development-cookbook-second-edition)*. This book is a must-buy for anyone looking for maximizing Visualforce, especially in Classic or SF1.

```
  <style>
    .requiredBlock {
       ... book is copyrighted so I don't want to expose the CSS but 
           you could just copy the SFDC styling
    }

    .requiredInput {
       ... see copyright note
    }
  </style>
```

**Use a proxy object**

For inputText fields, replace them with inputFields and bind them to a controller getter/setter for an SObject with field types that you care about - Date, Text, TextArea, DateTime, etc.

```
public Account proxyForMyObject {
    get { return proxyForMyObject == null ? proxyForMyObject = new Account() : proxyforMyObject;}
    set;
}
```

Then in the VF page, bind `apex:inputFields` to the `proxyForMyObject` as in:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputText value ="My text area long field"> 
    <apexInputField required="true" value={!proxyForMyObject.Description}"/>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
    <apex:outputText value ="My decimal field"> 
    <apexInputField required="true" value={!proxyForMyObject.AnnualRevenue}"/>
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

When your action method executes, copy the values from the `proxyForMyObject` into your real object and do what you will.

```
PageReference myAction () {
   MyObject myObj = new MyObject();
   myObj.Some_Decimal_Field__c d = proxyForMyObject.AnnualRevenue; 
   myObj.Some_Long_Text_Field__c t = proxyForMyObject.Description; 
   ...
}
```

I've used both methods; preferring the latter ONLY to get the OOTB datepicker rather than mess around with jQuery plugins. The latter is a trick and requires good commenting in your VF page and controller to explain why you are doing this.

Since Classic, is, well, Classic and SFDC energies are being directed into Lightning, I wouldn't worry too much about SFDC changing the Classic required styling.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a InputValidation component taking help of [Controller Component Communication](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Controller_Component_Communication)

1. Created PageControllerBase class (as it is specified)
2. Created ComponentControllerBase class (as it is specified)
3. myVFPComponent

**(Visualforce Component)**

```
`<apex:component controller="MyComponentController">`

      `<style type="text/css">`
         .verticalLine {
              border-left: 2px solid red; padding-left: 2px;
            }
          .roundBorder {
              border: 2px solid red; padding-left: 2px;
            }
       </style>
```

```
    <!-- Component Definition -->
    <!-- Vertical line (left solid line) will show normally for required attribute. 
    In case of error, textbox will be shown as round border -->
    <apex:outputPanel>
        <div>
           <apex:inputText value="{!FirstName}" styleClass="{!IF(isError,'roundBorder', 'verticalLine')}"/>           
        </div>
        <div>
            <apex:outputLabel rendered="{!isError}" value="Error:" style="color: red; font-weight:bold;"/>
            <apex:outputLabel rendered="{!isError}" value="You must enter a value." style="color: red;"/>
        </div>        
    </apex:outputPanel> 
</apex:component>
```

4. MyComponentController

**Component Controller**

```
public with sharing class MyComponentController extends ComponentControllerBase {   
  public String FirstName {get;set;}
  public Boolean isError {get;set;}    
}
```

5. **My Visualforce Page**

`<apex:page controller="MyPageController">

<apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
            <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
                <apex:outputLabel value="Enter First Name:"/>
                <c:myVFPComponent pageControllerAttribute="{!this}" id="compId"/>

            </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom">
            <apex:commandButton style="font-size: 12pt; color: black" action="{!callComponentControllerMethod}" value="Verify" rerender="compId"/> 
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>`

6. **MyPageController**

`public with sharing class MyPageController extends PageControllerBase {`

```
public MyComponentController myComponentController { get; set; }

  public override void setComponentController(ComponentControllerBase compController) {
    myComponentController = (MyComponentController)compController;
  }

  public override ComponentControllerBase getMyComponentController() {
    return myComponentController;
  }

  public PageReference callComponentControllerMethod() {
    try {
            myComponentController.isError = false;  //make error as false

            //verify validation
            if(String.isBlank(myComponentController.FirstName)) {
                myComponentController.isError = true;
                throw new MyCustomException ('Value is required'); //dummy error
            }
            return null;           
        } catch (Exception ex)
        {
             ApexPages.Message msg = new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.Error, ex.getMessage());
             ApexPages.addMessage(msg);            
        }
        return null;
  } 
}
```

**Screenshot (initially)**

[image: inputMandatory]

> Without providing input value, it will throw the error like this:

[image: input error]

Comment: I have already post it at my blog: http://santanuboral.blogspot.com/2017/01/visualforce-input-validation-component.html